# Returns a new HashMap that maps the words in list to their number of occurrences

Tags: java

counts()

Return type: HashMap

Parameter list: a ArrayList parameter list

Action:
Returns a new HashMap that maps the words in list to their number of occurrences

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> counts( ArrayList<String> words ) {

        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        for ( String w : words ) {

            if( !map.containsKey( w ) )  {
                map.put( w, 1 );
            }
            else{
                map.put( w, map.get( w ) + 1 );
            }
        }
        return map;
    }
```

It doesn't display anything.

Comment: I don't see any code to display anything.

Comment: If you want it to display anything, perhaps you should print the returned map.

Comment: Are you doing any `System.out.println` with the value returned from `counts` method from where you're calling it ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the "results" of your method, you need to iterate through all your keys, then display the output of the values to console:

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> counts( ArrayList<String> words ) {

    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    for ( String w : words ) {

        if( !map.containsKey( w ) )  {
            map.put( w, 1 );
        }
        else{
            map.put( w, map.get( w ) + 1 );
        }
    }
    String wrd = map.getKeys();
    for(String mWrd : wrd){
     System.out.println("There are " + map.getValue(mWrd) + " instances of " + mWrd);
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Simple `System.out.println(map)` will also print the key-value pairs but not nicely as above :)